# Describing my algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence, pseudocode

**Overview**

I'm in a strange place here.  I've written an algorithm, and am now not certain how to document it.  I'm looking for assistance in turning this logic into a precise description.

**Details**

I have a method that takes a variable number of groups as input and spits out a large set of results.  The number of results varies with the distribution of items in the groups and the number of groups.  I can calculate the number of results that will be created as such:

*In Psudocode:*

`(# of groups -1) * (# items in group 1) * (# items in group 2) * ... * (# items in group n)`

*In English:*

The number of groups minus one, times the number of items in group 1, times the number of items in group 2, times the number of items in group 3 ... etc.

**Question**

Both the pseudocode and English descriptions above seem unwieldy.

How do I more succinctly describe this algorithm?  Is there a compact mathematical formula?  Or can it be described with more precise words? Better Pseudocode? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the intended use of this algorithm. Maybe the description could formulate better from a real-world example of how/when to use it.

Comment: How about "The product of the orders of each group and one less than the number of groups"?

Comment: Do you mean "group" as the algebraic structure?

Comment: Why does the documentation need to be incredibly concise? A simple sentence or two is adequate. And you've already written enough to describe it perfectly well. Sometimes a concise mathematical formula is less readable than a few extra words.

Comment: @Jordan - "group" is meant in a generic sense here, as well as the usage of the term "set"

Comment: @woodchips - Even though in this case, the need remains - it's good advice none-the-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my go:

(n-1) * (product of cardinality across sets 1..n) where n = # of groups

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [capital Pi notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) to express this very neatly.  Model the groups as sets and use the [cardinality notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) to mean `# of items in group`.

Answer (score 1):

It is like (N-1)*Mult(k(i))(i from 0 to N-1)

Mathematical: **DIRECT PRODUCT OF GROUPS**

Go here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups

And look for:

```
===Finite direct products===
```

[image]

Dont forget to multiply with N-1  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is clearest to me, and probably most people with an OO background instead of an abstract math degree.

```
(# of groups - 1) * (group1.size) * (group2.size) * ... * (groupN.size)
```